# Falla en programa de números primos c++

Tags: c++, números-primos

Buenas he estado haciendo un ejercicio para determinar si un numero ingresado es número primo o no, aparentemente funciona, pero al pasarlo por una test falla. Ahora es cuando no se en que número o números en especifico el programa no de el resultado correcto. Agradecería me lo indicaran (los test de tiempo de ejecución y de números negativos si los consigue superar).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int num) {
    int count=0;
    bool prime=false;

    for(int i=1; i< sqrt(num); i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count ==1 && count<=2)
    {
        prime=true;
    }
    if(prime==true){
        cout<<"es primo";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No es primo";
    }
    return prime;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;
    cin>> num;
    isPrime(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buenos días, nos podrías dar tu código completo por favor, junto con tu `int main()` para analizar mejor

Comment: Vale lo editaré, aunque realmente solo hago llamado a la función.

Comment: Ok me parece bien.

Comment: Puedes retornar directamente el valor en lugar de asignar la variable y esperar al final para retornar. Por cierto, primos son los números positivos mayores que 1. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Número_primo

Comment: `    bool prime=true;

    for(int i=2; i< sqrt(num); i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            prime=false;
            break;
        }`

Comment: @Mateo Si claro pero el test exige que se compruebe con números negativos también aunque como dices todo numero negativo no es número primo.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier mejor aún, inicia en 3 y aumenta de a 2. Te ahorras la mitad de los números. Puedes ponerlo como respuesta por cierto.

Comment: Pero no pasaría nada si iniciamos en 2 o 3 en su defecto, que por ejemplo le introduzca el1 para que lo compruebe?

Comment: @EiderYesidObando si divides cualquier número entre otro mayor nunca dará resto `0`

Comment: @Francisco Javier Si ya me di cuenta muchas gracias, en ese caso lo modificare con las sugerencias por que lo aplique directamente y me dio resultados incorrectos.

Comment: En qué momento falla el programa? probé con los números primos del 1 al 100 y todas son correctas...

Comment: Ese es mi problema que parece que funciona pero si lo ingreso un test no lo pasa, hay alguno o varios valores donde al parecer no da el resultado correcto.

Comment: *pero si lo ingreso un test* -> a que te refieres con esto? Muéstranos las pruebas. Seguro con números negativos muere el programa :S

Comment: Como puedo compartir las pruebas que hice? es de una página llamada codewars, y no aun con números negativos da el resultado correcto, tal vez sea con números muy grandes donde de fallas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo tienes casi bien, el ciclo ha de empezar por 2 e ir hasta la mitad del número y los casos if variarlos así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int num) {
int count=0;
bool prime=true;
if(num!=0 || num!=1 || num!=2 || num!=4){
    for(int i=2; i< num / 2; i++){
            if(num%i==0){
                count++;
                prime = false; 
            }
        }
}else{
    prime = false;
}
return prime;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;
    cin>> num;
    isPrime(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Así de manera predeterminada muestras true y si ocurre la condición del ciclo, es que es falso...

Para completar-lo para que vaya más rápido, puedes salir del ciclo si se cumple alguna vez la condición del ciclo aunque solo lo hará rápido cuando sea falso...

Comment: Él OP ha puesto en el `for`: i< sqrt(num), mientras que tú has puesto: `i< num / 2`, pero él lo tiene "casi bien"; por cierto, ¿y el `count++`?...

Comment: El count no sirve para nada se ha quedado huerfano...

Comment: Hasta la raiz cuadrada es suficiente

Comment: No encuentro sentido el uso del `sqrt()`, pero el programa funcionaba bien :)...

Comment: La raíz cuadrada era una "forma" de optimización ya que dice que no es necesario comparar todos los numero si no con valores de su raíz cuadrada por lo que ahorra más tiempo aunque no se si este correcto.

Comment: Bueno, en este caso no lo utiliza y aún así verificaste la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Asignas el valor `true` de forma predeterminada a la variable `prime`.
Si dentro del bucle `for`se da alguna divisón con resto `0`, dicha variable pasa a ser `false`y se sale del bucle.
Más tarde, dependiendo de su valor se imprime por pantalla el resultado y se devuelve el `return` de la función.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int num) {
    bool prime=true;

    for(int i=2; i< sqrt(num); i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            prime=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(prime==true){
        cout<<"es primo";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No es primo";
    }
    return prime;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;
    cin>> num;
    isPrime(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo por el código tu idea es contar los divisores de N y si son más de 2 (1 y el propio N) retornar que no es primo.

Un detalle en el código es que debes incluir la raíz cuadrada en el ciclo de comprobación. Pues si el número es un cuadrado perfecto (digamos 81), el ciclo se realizará del 1 .. 8, no incluyendo al 9 que es la raíz cuadrada de 81 y por lo tanto lo divide.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int num) {
    if(num <= 1)
    {
        cout << "No es primo";
        return false;
    }
    int count=0;
    bool prime=false;

    for(int i=1; i <= sqrt(num); i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        prime=true;
    }
    
    if(prime==true){
        cout<<"es primo";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No es primo";
    }
    return prime;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;
    cin>> num;
    isPrime(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Una implementación más limpia de la función y mantendiendo tu idea sería la siguiente:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int num) {
    if (num <= 1)
        return false;

    for(int i=2; (long long) i * i <= (long long) num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num;
    cin>> num;
    if (isPrime(num))
        cout << "Es primo";
    else
        cout << "No es primo";
    return 0;
}
```

Notar que podemos evitar la llamada a la función `sqrt` comprobando el cuadrado de `i` (`i * i <= N`), lo que sería menos costoso computacionalmente. Además se debe castear a `long long`.

Espero ayude :)